# Xcode 4.6 develop iOS 3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-3.x

I want to learn iOS development. I have a jailbroken first gen iPod touch with iOS 3.1.3, that I was hoping to use for testing and running my app. I am running Mountain Lion with XCode 4.6 which allows me to only deploy down to as low as iOS 4.3.

I was wondering if it would be possible for me to develop iOS 3.1 apps with my XCode? or would I have to download older versions of XCode and iOS SDKs to do so?

Comment: You will have to use older versions - Xcode 4.6 supports iOS4.3 and higher only.

Comment: Learning on such an older device is just going to hinder your efforts. There are so many new features in iOS and Objective-C that you won't be able to use with iOS 3.1.3. Find a used device you can buy that runs iOS 6. Or just use the simulator.

Comment: Even though @rmaddy is certainly right, I personally feel that knowing how to do proper memory management using MRC (as opposed to ARC) has given me much better insights - those are some of the differences that he is talking about. However the time you have to invest in understanding those dated things will never be payed back in full.

Comment: @Till I agree that learning MRC before ARC is good. But I was actually thinking about things like all of the modern Objective-C syntax for properties, array and dictionary literals, and array indexes. And then there is GCD and multitasking. And there are so many API changes since 3.1.3.

Comment: @Till I agree entirely, but you don't need to go all the way back 3.x to learn MRC, that is just a compiler flag.

Comment: Yah yah yah, you convinced me... NOT :D ... cheers mates @MikeD & rmaddy

Comment: @Till I strongly suspect it's possible, but you'll need to re-enable `armv6` in a plist somewhere and use `lipo` to add armv6 to `crt1.o` (`lipo`ed out of an old SDK), and for any debugging to work you'll need to grab `DeviceSupport/3.1.3` from an old SDK too (and even then I don't know if it'll work with recent Xcode).

Comment: @tc you wont get a deployment target below 4.3 to compile though...

Comment: @Till I'm fairly sure you can if you know what files to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll have to update to a newer version of iOS, or use bootcamp to boot to Lion with an older XCode.